# Data modelling, calculation and visualization tools?

Tags: microsoft-excel, software-rec, database, data-visualization

I often need to make decisions based on various kinds of data and their calculation results/visualizations respectively. For simple, tabular data I usually make Excel spreadsheets, however most of the time the data is too complex for this.

A pseudo example:

The only thing you know is that you want to go on holiday this year. For this, you got a time frame of 2 weeks, and you'd like to visit 2 places at least. So there are multiple options here, like making 50/50 for each place, or 20/80. This all depends on information like: When do the flights depart? When are there hotels to stay available? How much does option 1, option 2, option 3 costs? Do you visit the places in a row, or do you head back in between?

For this, I could easily write an application. Modelling such data in a OOP language is pretty easily, however it always requires a lot of boilerplate code to wire the whole thing up, which can be very daunting.

So, are there any applications where one can create 'models' and forms for the data and easily click things together? Some kind of advanced Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding upon Excel: check [PowerQuery](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/introduction-to-microsoft-power-query-for-excel-HA104003940.aspx) from Microsoft (it's free). Any modern BI tool can do what you asked: SAS, Informatica, Cognos, MS SQL reporting server, Oracle BI, etc. See: [this list](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_intelligence_tools) for example.

Comment: BI? Business Intelligence? Is that what I should be looking for? (It's sometimes hard to find something when you're not aware of what it is called.)

Answer (score 0):

Power Query is a great tool for getting raw data into shape. For modelling data and adding advanced calculations, I would also use the Power Pivot Add-In from Microsoft.  Power Query can feed directly into a Power Pivot Model.  This site is probably the best resource:

http://www.powerpivotpro.com/what-is-powerpivot/

I think the strength of this approach is all the small but crucial data (little reference / lookup / translation / weight tables) that turns a data dump into a great model can be typed into Excel, then directly integrated into your model.